# how to proceed with the make command in ubuntu 10.04 to install NS2?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, ns2

actually, im quite new to ubuntu 10.04, and i used it to proceed with my cognitive radio project. therefore, i need to install ns2 with the crcn patch. unfortunately, i cannot proceed with the installation as when i invoke the make command, the results came out as error below

```
make: CXX@: Command not found
make: *** [tools/random.o]Error 127
```

when i invoke the `makedepend`, nothing happen.. please help me, im desperate as i dont know where else i can found the solution. thanks you in advance.

Comment: We need to see the makefile and the command you used to run it.

Comment: this is my Makefile, the compiler i already have change from @CC@ to gcc-4.3.. please help me, im really new to this, i just learn ubuntu and ns2 1 month ago.. thank you in advance, i will try g++ --version later. –  amiruldin

Comment: do click the link from the user below, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to run `configure` or something first.  Usually that will replace a token like `@CXX@` in the `Makefile.in` with the name of your compiler, since different systems use different compilers.  Based in this error it looks like that replacement wasn't successful and your makefile is corrupted.

So based on this error either you didn't run `configure`, or the `configure` step didn't work completely.  Building software is an orderly process; you can't proceed to the next step until the first step is successful.

I assume you do have a C++ compiler installed on your system?  If you type `g++ --version` is it successful or do you get an error?

Comment: this is my [Makefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x89j98ujmiliyl7/Untitled%203.odt), the compiler i already have change from @CC@ to gcc-4.3.. please help me, im really new to this, i just learn ubuntu and ns2 1 month ago.. thank you in advance, i will try g++ --version later.

Comment: You should never import any source code (including makefiles) into a word processor like Writer for any reason.  Use a text editor, like `gedit` or `emacs` or `nano` or something, and when uploading to dropbox just upload the text file.

Comment: This makefile is really wrong.  Did you copy it from `Makefile.in` by hand?  That's not correct.  You are supposed to run the `configure` command which will create `Makefile` for you, replacing all the appropriate `@...@` tokens.  Please read the instructions for building from source and follow them: they will be on the website and/or in a `README` or `INSTALL` file that comes with the source.

Comment: i edited my Makefile using nano and i follow the step from this website,https://sites.google.com/a/seecs.edu.pk/network-technologies-tcp-ip-suite/home/broadcast-data-over-multi-channels-multi-interface-network-in-ns-2-yasir-saleem/ns-2-installation, what should i do now, should i remove the makefile directory or just configure it ?

Comment: I've never tried to build ns2 but those instructions look pretty wrong to me.  I would recommend reading the ones on the ns-2 website: http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-build.html  Although if you've already got most of the prerequisites you can skip building those and just follow the instructions for ns-2.

Comment: thank you very much, i really appreciate it, but i already used that website as my reference but it still fail, i think the problem might involve my laptop specs.. any other suggestion please?? thank you in advance

Comment: @amiruldin I agree with all of MadScientist's comments. His ns-build link looks much more credible.

Comment: It fails the same way?  That seems unlikely.  I recommend starting from scratch: remove the source directory, unpack it again, apply your patch, then run "./configure" and look at the output and be sure it doesn't report any errors or anything, then run "make" (do _not_ edit any makefiles by hand).  If you see errors and you don't know how to resolve them you probably need to start a new question (unless the errors are identical).  And/or you can ask for help on the ns mailing lists: http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-lists.html presumably they have much more experience.

Comment: thank you very much, i really reallly appreciate your help, and im sorry to bother u guys with my lack in this topic, sorry.. i tried the configure command, and it change my makefile, nevertheless, im stil stuck at the same place.. i will try start the project from scratch, sorry guys..